# how can get text from image to action bar like truecaller

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make action bar like truecaller it get the name of true caller from the image to the action bar when scrolling how can I do one like that

[image: image one]

[image: image two]

[image: image three]
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

You can see that "true caller" moved up to action bar when it scolling

Comment: you can try this library project if it works for you https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar